# How to use Date and Time Picker in same control in WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently working on WP8 and my requirement is to create a item which allows user to select both Date and Time and the details are combined and added in TextBox.

Can anyone suggest is there any third party control using which I can add this control or I should just create Custom Control ?

I am aware of creating custom control but it becomes difficult when managing data.

Comment: Please check Windows Phone Toolkit. It's available through NUGET and includes variety of WP controls https://phone.codeplex.com/ I have done WP development in the past and used this toolkit. Project home page mentions it has DateTimePickers control/s but I don't exactly remember if it is combined one (which you need) or separate date and time pickers. Worth a check.

Comment: I am using this, but only individual Date and Time Picker controls are available :-(

Comment: Yes checked again now. I am afraid you will have to create one and perhaps think of releasing it for people. In case someone needs in the future.

Comment: The control you describe is appropriate and expected for *Windows* but unsuitable for *Phone* where there's limited space and people have to use their thumbs to select dates and/or times. Users will not appreciate a UI that's different from the rest of the device